# anaconda build can't use patch?

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

after anaconda build submit .
I got an Error in the building page:
98    Did not find 'patch' in: /opt/miniconda/envs/_build/bin:/opt/miniconda/bin:/home/binstar/env/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

Comment: I face the same issue. Here is my log: https://anaconda.org/zeehio/scikit-umfpack/builds/6/0. It looks like the Docker images being used in Anaconda builds do not have patch installed, so this is probably a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this issue got solved in the [development branch](https://github.com/Anaconda-Server/anaconda-build/commit/779107d1f1c58ce80bfd34291ae347c832645375). According to [this issue](https://github.com/Anaconda-Server/anaconda-build/issues/24) it was fixed one month ago (December 2015), although I still face it.

Meanwhile you can use local building with `conda-build --py 3.5 ...`.